# Plugin to redirect after login

Tags: login

Is it possible to have a plugin that redirects the user to a specific page after log in? (instead of using the normal login module or menu item?)

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You can check the available extensions on Joomla extensions directory here: https://extensions.joomla.org/tags/login-redirect/

Comment: And as for a new member here on JSE: please do your own research on the subject before asking “is it possible…” questions and please include some details with your question that shows that you already searched for solutions on your issue before asking for help in this community. Please read here a bit more about this community: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can ! Look on the event where you can add events
https://docs.joomla.org/Special:MyLanguage/Plugin/Events/User#onUserLogin